# Why this error happend? nodejs Error: write EIO

Tags: node.js, express

I made a webApp with nodejs + mongodb + Backbone on window7-32bit, everything goes fine until yestoday. but I got this error this morning:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: write EIO
    at errnoException (net.js:883:11)
    at Object.afterWrite (net.js:700:19)
```

I googled around but no luck, I tried update node, and then got this error:

```
npm ERR! Error: write EIO
npm ERR!     at errnoException (net.js:883:11)
npm ERR!     at Object.afterWrite (net.js:700:19)
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this log at:
npm ERR!     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
npm ERR! or email it to:
npm ERR!     <npm-@googlegroups.com>

npm ERR! System Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "update"
npm ERR! cwd C:\work\selink
npm ERR! node -v v0.10.4
npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.18
npm ERR! syscall write
npm ERR! code EIO
npm ERR! errno EIO
```

why this error happened suddenly? any hint about it?

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Try upgrading Node through the downloadable installers on http://nodejs.org/download/, perhaps that works better.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I have just been playing with Unicode support in Windows command prompt, using the code-page 65001 I can't get npm to install, giving me the above error. Changing the code-page to 850 `chcp 850` and running the exact same npm command it then works fine.

Thus your problem could very well be related to the encoding your environment is in.

Comment: This error happened to me when tried to install Coffeescript today in a Windows 7 -64 bit- but this solution worked

Comment: This worked for me too. Just a note, the command in cmd to change the code page is chcp 850

Comment: and If I would want to show a Unicode Text on prompt ? shouldn't this print ?

Comment: Thank you, you're a lifesaver.

Comment: WOW! I am so happy this answer was here. Thanks so much. I guarantee I would never have figured this out on my own.

Comment: Don't know why I suddenly started getting the error, don't know why this fixed it, but it did and I'm grateful!

Answer (score 0):

Changing the codepage to CP850 works, but if you want to get Unicode characters, you shoud use [iconv-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite)  module