# Node.js throws write EIO exception at random time

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, winston

I'm writing a game server using node.js + socket.io + Winston (logger) and my server dies every day because of this exception:

```
Error: write EIO
at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
at Object.afterWrite (net.js:718:19)
```

I suspect it could be the way I'm using Winston. I have `server.js` and `room.js` classes in which I require Winston with this statement : `var winston = require('winston');`  and in `server.js` I register the file logging with:

```
winston.add(winston.transports.File, { filename: 'server.log' });
winston.handleExceptions(new winston.transports.File({ filename: 'errors.log' }))
```

In `room.js` I simply call the `winston.info()` method.

Could it be because of the many `room` instances or something ?

Comment: If on Windows check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035399/why-this-error-happend-nodejs-error-write-eio and if on linux this happens due to read/write error like when device is disconnected.

Comment: The server is ubuntu linux. What can I do to prevent this behavior ? Even with "uncaughtException" event registered - my server is still dying when it happens

Comment: Haven't figured this one out yet. If I do I'll post here.

Comment: I'm getting the same error as well, and I'm using socket.io also. Error: write EIO
    at errnoException (net.js:904:11)
    at Object.afterWrite (net.js:720:19)

Comment: Get rid of it and write your own TCP socket..the best option if you are not using it to communicate with html page. That's what I did and no problems anymore..also socket.io is leaking memory and winston too. they are not suitable for big projects and many connections

Answer (score -2):

### PREVENT APP CRASH

:you can prevent your application crash by using this module [Node.js domain exception handler](https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html)
you can write your code inside domain block and it will never crash again.but be careful ,you must resolve your issue first