# NodeJs server crashing randomly: events.js:72 EIO

Tags: node.js, server

I'm running a NodeJs server on linux and after several hours up it crashes:

```
events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
          ^
Error: write EIO
    at errnoException (net.js:901:11)
    at Object.afterWrite (net.js:718:19)
```

Can anyone help me please??
Why downvoting?

Comment: Have you looked at this?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035399/why-this-error-happend-nodejs-error-write-eio

Comment: Can you tell me what version of node you're running (type ```node -v?``` in bash)? I'm looking at net.js in the node.js library currently available on github and line 901 seems to be a blank line... and the line after is ```if (pipe) {``` which doesn't seem likely to be connected to the error you're having. Similarly, line 718 is just ```case 'ucs2':``` which seems unlikely to be causing this particular exception.

Comment: @Pedro: Thanks but i'm running Linux

Comment: @Peter David Carter v4.4.2

Comment: @Pedro: Please read the complete question before answering.

Comment: I read the complete question, did not answer, and know you're running Linux. I wondered if there would be overlap in the solutions. Clearly there was not.

Answer (score 0):

I actually managed to fix it. This helped a lot: [How to make a node.js application run permanently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12701259/how-to-make-a-node-js-application-run-permanently)

The problem was that the process was trying to write into a closed terminal.